# PHP Gmail API get message info for From,To, Cc, Bcc, Reply-To, Body, Attachments

Tags: php, email, gmail-api

I'm using Gmail API https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/ .

But I can't find single message info like- FROM, TO, CC, BCC, REPLY-TO with name and address.
Need output as-

```
$msg['fromAddress'] = 'fromemail@gmail.com';
$msg['fromName'] = 'From Name';
$msg['to'] = array('John Lok' => 'johnlok@gmail.com', 'Smither Fan'=>'smither@gmail.com');
$msg['cc'] = array('krish Hosa' => 'krish23@gmail.com', 'Singam Hat'=>'singhamso@gmail.com');
$msg['bcc'] = array('Loban' => 'lobandash@gmail.com', 'Krain Root'=>'krainroot@gmail.com');
$msg['body'] = 'sample Message Text';
$msg['attachments'] = array('Flower.jpg' => 'https://filelink.com/files/Flower-d9edkifsk3edmfsdf94rffjofs.jpg', 'Bill List.pdf'=>'https://filelink.com/files/Bill-List-34324234mfskfsofsc.pdf');
$msg['reply-to'] = array('From Name' => 'fromemail@gmail.com');
```

Answer (score 3):

Gmail API requires that those mail headers fulfills the requirements of [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822). Then, all those headers should be compiled in a URL-safe string as defined in [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7). [Here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages_with_attachments) you can see an example of this approach to send mails.

I understand that you need to read those headers from existing mails. If that is correct, then you only have to reverse the former approach. First you would need to use [`users.messages.get()`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) to read an instance of the existing mail. In the `raw` field it is stored in the previously mentioned URL-safe string. Please, ask me any further doubts.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Headers in "users.threads.get()" is useable for my wanted information about the messages.

Comment: Thank you for your update @MamedulIslam! If this answer has helped you to solve your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/589350) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.